# JavaScript Fading Slides Out, Fixing Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been pounding my head for the past 3-4 hours trying to figure out the best solution to this. I have a form and at the beginning you can select which slides of the form you want to fill out.[image]

Once any of these are selected it will show a section for that selection. For example if I selected home
[image]

What is the best method to show the slides based on the checkboxes? Also, if you notice I have a next button on the bottom of each slide, how can I change that automatically to be replaced with the next div item?

My current code to check the selected boxes and insert into an array is

`var arr = [];
        function validate() {
            if (document.getElementById('home-form').checked) {
                arr.push("home");
            }
            if (document.getElementById('auto-form').checked) {
                arr.push("auto");
            }
            if (document.getElementById('life-form').checked) {
                arr.push("life");
            }
            if (document.getElementById('flood-form').checked) {
                arr.push("flood");
            }
            if (document.getElementById('umbrella-form').checked) {
                arr.push("umbrella");
            }
            if (document.getElementById('renters-form').checked) {
                arr.push("renters");
            }
            if (document.getElementById('landlord-form').checked) {
                arr.push("landlord");
            }
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just knocked this up together for you: https://jsfiddle.net/r344Lygt/2/

When the start button is clicked, the checked checkboxes are iterated over and added to the `selectedSteps` array.

**JavaScript**

```
var selectedSteps = [];
var currentStep = 0;

$('.start').on('click',function(){
  $('.nav input').each(function(){
    var i=0;
    if($(this).prop('checked')){ 
      selectedSteps.push($(this).attr('id'));
      i++;
    }
  });
  $('.splash').hide();
  goToForm(0);
});

$('[data-next]').on('click',function(){
  if(currentStep < (selectedSteps.length-1)) {
    currentStep++;
    goToForm(currentStep);
  } else {
    $('[data-form]').hide();
    $('[data-form="complete"]').show();
  }
});

function goToForm(step){
  $('[data-form]').hide();
  $('[data-form="'+selectedSteps[step]+'"]').show();
  $('.status span').css('width', 100 / selectedSteps.length * (currentStep+1) +'%');
}
```

Comment: Working fine on jsfiddle but wont work at all on my site.

Comment: What part doesn't work? If you have copied and pasted the HTML, CSS & JS from the Fiddle into your site, and have jQuery loaded, there's no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, just realize you can view the source code super easy on jsfiddle. I greatly appreciate your help, thank you so much.

Comment: For any future people reading this, jsfiddle does not include the load type in the code boxes, you need to view source and copy/paste or include the load type. in EX: $(window).on('load', function() {

Comment: Was about to say that the link you posted works - I guess you had sorted it by the time I clicked on it! No problem, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps,

- Create HTML templates for those slides (Basic,Home,Auto,Umbrella)
- You can push these HTML templates. Example:

  ```
  var Basic = '<div class="basic">
  //Your HTML for Basic slide goes here..
  </div>';

  var Basic = '<div class="Umbrella">
  //Your HTML for Umbrella slide goes here..
  </div>';

  // So on.....
  ```
- Have a parent slide div(Let's say #parent id), and when the Basic/Home//Umbrella/..etc is clicked load the respective template to the inner HTML of the parent.
  Example:When Basic is clicked.

  ```
  $("#parent").html(Basic); //If you are using JQuery
  ```

Comment: That still doesn't explain how to change the buttons on the bottom to go to the next slide